# Why is REST called an architecture style?

Tags: rest

Why is REST an architecture style whereas SOAP is considered as a protocol?  Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Architecture is about high level design. REST is an example of that because it is only a set of design guidelines like that your API should be stateless. It doesn't tell you exactly what language to use or what your code should look like.

Other examples of architectural questions are

- How should my modules communicate?
- How should I structure my data?
- What guiding principles can I apply?

Non examples are:

- What is the name of the function that allocates memory?
- Do I use i++ or ++i?